# Why does adding a related_name to my model break existing querysets that use set_all?

Tags: django

So I had to add a related_name to a simple model, and this seems to have broken some html on a couple pages.

Here is the model with the related_name

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    example_a = models.ForeignKey(example_a)
    example_b = models.ForeignKey(example_b, related_name='examplesb')
    node = models.ForeignKey(Node, null=True)
    time = models.DateTimeField()
```

I believe the culprit is set_all in the template.  Is there a quick fix for this?  Why is this happening?

```
{% for i in demo.testmodel_set.all|dictsort:"time_start" %}
```

Comment: Because that's what it does; it changes the default from testmodel_set to whatever you define. Why does this surprise you?

Comment: @david did you get to solve your problem? Was my answer below useful to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the adding of related_name caused the problems, try using that related name `examplesb` instead of `testmodel_set`.

```
{% for i in demo.examplesb.all|dictsort:"time_start" %}
```

Comment: Did this help you?